# With what unit are river flow speeds indicated on the Genshtab Soviet military maps?

Tags: maps, russia

On the Genshtab (Генштаб) Soviet military maps, I can read that [this ford through the stream Вертный](https://nakarte.me/#m=13/64.85280/58.07682&l=T/C) has a stony bottom, a depth of at most 4 dm, and a width of 29 m (under typical circumstances)¹.  That is indeed fordable.  It also indicates that the flow velocity is 0.6, but I can't find anywhere what unit the velocity is in.  I've found an [English language legend](http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/EART/pdf/soviet.pdf) as well as a [more detailed Russian language legend](http://www.realbiker.ru/Map/TopoSymbols/Gidrografia1.jpg) — screenshot below — but neither appears to describe the units.  I would expect it to be km/h, but it might be m/s, which is a factor 3.6 different.  What unit is it in?  I'm starting to learn Russian but I don't understand enough yet to find this information.

[image: Genshtab legend]

I'm sure the quantity is speed and not total flow, because [this small mountain stream](https://nakarte.me/#m=13/64.85488/59.53302&l=T) (15 metre wide, 0.5 metre deep) has 2.5 speed units, whereas [this river downstream](https://nakarte.me/#m=12/67.03524/52.42264&l=T) (1310 metre wide, 10 metre deep) has 0.4 speed units.

---

¹<sup>These maps are awesome… where else in the world can you find such detail on topographic maps? Sorry, that's not my question here but I just wanted to say that :)</sup>

Comment: I read no Russian but a further possibility is the volume flow in cubic metres per second - this is how river flows are often measured elsewhere

Comment: @ChrisH No, it must be speed: [this small stream in the mountains](https://nakarte.me/#m=13/64.85488/59.53302&l=T) has 2.5, whereas far downstream [near the mouth of the main river](https://nakarte.me/#m=12/67.03524/52.42264&l=T) the value is 0.4.

Comment: good, that helps. Your example in the question just happened to be plausible in those units. Of course depth and speed matter directly for fording, in a way that total flow doesn't - but total flow matters for other things.

Comment: @ChrisH I've edited the information into the question.

Comment: @gerrit I don't see any fords on the map link you've provided - 29/0.4K does describe the river, but it doesn't mean there's any ford. Fords it's a "бр." supplied with details.

Comment: @Usurer I know, but I don't need any officially indicated ford to cross a stream/river when I'm hiking in the mountains.  Nor do infantry, for whom this information was originally intended. An official ford is more about vehicles. My link does show a blue cross, though.

Comment: @Usurer Although it appears that the blue cross just indicates the point that the numbers relate to and nothing else, there is a [hiking trail crossing the river here](http://www.yugyd-va.ru/turizm-i-otdyh/turisticheskie-marshruty/turisticheskie-marshruty/d-aranets-b-ozernaya-b-vangyr-b-zhelannaya/), so it's a ford for hikers.  I suppose the official ford symbol on the map means a ford for vehicles.

Comment: @Usurer On second thought, maybe the dashed line there indicates a winter road and not a hiking trail; but the map is old and both openstreetmap and [wikiloc](https://www.wikiloc.com/hiking-trails/pripolarural-2012-3360212) indicate that the route from Аранец to Озерная should cross the Вертный right there.

Comment: @Usurer I think [this is a photo of the spot](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/101886602878882039714/album/5789989881853084625/5789990222820292354).

Comment: @gerrit Yeah, it's no doubt that one doesn't need an "official" ford to cross the river, I was just saying, that you were saying "this ford" and there's no ford sign on the map and that's a bit confusing =)

Comment: @gerrit AFAIK dashed line is a glade. The map is ancient, so, most probably, there's just a regular forest there right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88535/discussion-between-gerrit-and-usurer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's meter per second. See the more detailed legend explanation at [this huge pdf](ftp://ftp.easytrace.com/other/symbols25k.pdf)

The text means "Arrows that show rivers' flow direction (0.2 is a speed of the flow in m/s)"

[image]

Comment: Good ifnd!  Only now I realised that a later legend item in the more succinct legend that I found does indicate that flow speed is in m/s, so I could have guessed that the earlier legend item does, too.